# mysql master/master replication problem

Tags: replication, mariadb

I am having a problem with one of my MySQL servers running CentOS 7.  I have it almost setup with a master master replication status.  But I keep getting this:

`MariaDB [(none)]> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Connecting to master
                  Master_Host: 192.168.220.80
                  Master_User: replication
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000037
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 245
               Relay_Log_File: mariadb-relay-bin.000001
                Relay_Log_Pos: 4
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000037
             Slave_IO_Running: Connecting
            Slave_SQL_Running: Yes
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 0
                   Last_Error: 
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 245
              Relay_Log_Space: 245
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 1045
                Last_IO_Error: error connecting to master 'replication@192.168.220.80:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 86400  message: Access denied for user 'replication'@'asm-sql01.borg.priv' (using password: YES)
               Last_SQL_Errno: 0
               Last_SQL_Error: 
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 0
1 row in set (0.00 sec)`

MariaDB [(none)]>

Comment: Did you read the part `Access denied for user 'replication'@'asm-sql01.borg.priv' (using password: YES)`? Is a permission issue.

Comment: yes.  I tried granting permission to all databases.  It wouldn't take.  I'm guessing I did something wrong...

Comment: Take a look here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/setting-up-replication/.  `GRANT REPLICATION SLAVE ON *.* TO 'replication_user'@'slave_host' IDENTIFIED BY 'bigs3cret'; FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`

Comment: I tried this from phpMyAdmin....I guess don't trust this?

Comment: Do I need to stop the slave process when doing this?

Comment: Of course, you need to `STOP SLAVE;`, grant it, flush it and `START SLAVE;`

Comment: Have you created this user on both the servers? and FUSH PRIVILEGES is very important.

Comment: Yes.  I have done flush privileges each time.  However I've moved past that.  I have a new error.

Comment: I just need to research this issue
               Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Binary log is not open'

Comment: I suspect this is a permissions issue.